# Passing model instances by id in serializer Django Rest Framework

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-rest-framework

When I post product_id in postman I am getting this result

```
{
    "id": 13,
    "user": 26,
    "product": null,
    "quantity": 1
}
```

which product is null, but I do not want this.

my serializer looks like this

```
class CartSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    product = ProductSerializer(required=False)

    class Meta:
        model = Cart
        fields = ['id', 'user', 'product', 'quantity']

    def create(self, validated_data):
        return Cart.objects.create(**validated_data)
```

I add product to cart from admin I get this

```
{
            "id": 7,
            "user": 26,
            "product": {
                "id": 8,
                "name": "Apple Watch 4 series",
                "brand": "Apple",
                "color": {
                    "id": 1,
                    "color": "Black"
                },
                "price": "250.00",
                "discount": 2,
                "images": [
                    {
                        "id": 6,
                        "product": 8,
                        "image": "http://localhost:8000/media/products/2019/12/09/b_Amazfit_Bip.jpg"
                    }
                ],
                "slug": "apple-watch-4-series"
            },
            "quantity": 1
```

that is exactly what I want but I cannot override serializer method. How can I do this? If I post product id I should get the result above shown. Thanks inadvance!

Comment: What you mean by *you cannot override serializer method*? Is there any problem?

Comment: Sorry i meant that i want to get desired result above shown

Comment: How can you return the `product` information if `product` is `null`?

Comment: @Nerd as @JPG said you should pass the `product_id`

Comment: If post `{'product': 8}` in the postman it should return all details but I cannot do this how can I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can create the custom serializer field

```
class CustomForeignKeyField(serializers.PrimaryKeyRelatedField):

    def get_queryset(self):
        return self.queryset

    def to_representation(self, value):
        value = super().to_representation(value)
        product = Product.objects.get(pk=value)
        return ProductSerializer(product).data
```

in serializer

```
class CartSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    product = CustomForeignKeyField(required=False, queryset=Prouct.objects.all() )

    class Meta:
        model = Cart
        fields = ['id', 'user', 'product', 'quantity']

    def create(self, validated_data):
        return Cart.objects.create(**validated_data)
```

it will accept product as int value and return json value in response. It can make generic for other. if you pass serilizer name also in constructor.

Answer (score 1):

In Django, any foreign key is saved with `_id` appended as post fix to the field name you have declared. But when you are sending some data to some API, you should use it without `_id` post fix. You should use `product` from postman. Serializer only get field which are declared in serializer Meta class. As your `product` field is optional, your serializer is not giving any error. So that is why you are getting `product` as `null` in your response. If you want to send data in `product_id` field instead of `product` field, you should change your serializer like this.

```
class CartSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    product_id = serializer.IntegerField(required=False)

    class Meta:
        model = Cart
        fields = ['id', 'user', 'product_id', 'quantity']

    def create(self, validated_data):
        return Cart.objects.create(**validated_data)

    def to_representation(self, validated_data):
        data = super().to_representation(validated_data)
        data.update({'product': ProductSerializer(instance.product).data})
        return data
```

Answer (score 0):

As of DRF 3.2.4, so long as you add

```
blank=True
```

to the models field like so:

```
class Posts(models.Model):
    country = models.ForeignKey(Country, blank=True)
```

then DRF will treat the field as optional when serializing and deserializing it (Note though that if there is no null=True on the model field, then Django will raise an error if you try to save an object to the database without providing the field).

See the answer here for more information:

DjangoRestFramework - correct way to add "required = false" to a ModelSerializer field?

If you are using pre-DRF 3.2.4, then you can override the field in the serializer and add required=False to it. See the documentation here for more information on specifying or overriding fields explicitily:

http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/#specifying-fields-explicitly

So something like this (Note that I did not fully test the code below but it should be something along these lines):

```
class PostsSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    country = serializers.PrimaryKeyRelatedField(required=False)
    class Meta:
        model = Posts
        fields = ('user', 'post', 'country',)
        depth=2

        def create(self, validated_data):
            return Posts.objects.create(**validated_data)
```

Comment: it returns the same `{
    "id": 26,
    "quantity": 1,
    "product": 8,
    "user": 26
}`

Comment: what can I do to return product details?

Comment: You add depth=2 in class serializer in below the fields

Comment: i added but it return user information not product information why is that?

Answer (score 0):

Add ProductSerializer inside many = True
    class CartSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

```
    product = ProductSerializer(required=False,many=True)

    class Meta:
        model = Cart
        fields = ['id', 'user', 'product', 'quantity']

    def create(self, validated_data):
        return Cart.objects.create(**validated_data)
```